# Terms for an PhD grant that covers everything

Tags: phd, funding, terminology

I am looking for the proper adjective that would carry the meaning that a grant for a PhD student covers everything (tuition fees, stipends, etc.). I believe one can use the expression "full grant", but I wonder whether there exists some more unambiguous adjective.

Comment: fully funded  is used

Answer (score 2):

You can just say/write *'funded PhD'* or *'fully funded PhD'* to avoid any ambiguity that may cause for any resume reviewer abroad.